# Can a WAP site go on a subdomain or does it need a new domain?

Tags: domains, subdomain, mobile

We planning to launch a mobile WAP site to our exiting customer lead tracking website. Is it necessary to buy a WAP domain or can we create a subdomain for our existing domain like `wap.example.com`?

Comment: People still make WAP sites?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do whatever you want. You can:

- get a .mobi domain just for the mobile website
- use a subdomain for the mobile content (I.e. m.domain.com)
- use media queries to display your site depending on the resolution of the device used to view it

On my new site I am developing I am using media queries. iIt's a small website so that easy to do. Facebook uses a subdomain. Use whatever works for you.